# Unknown disk found using diskutil, cannot delete

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, disk-utility

Using the command line, I wanted to see all available drives on my machine. So, I type

```
diskutil list
```

and besides Recovery HD and Macintosh HD, I notice this:

```
/dev/disk3
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *1.2 GB     disk3
1:        Apple_partition_map                         4.1 KB     disk3s1
2:                  Apple_HFS                         2.3 MB     disk3s2
```

Question 1: What is this? How did it get there?

Secondly, I don't know how to delete this disk. I try the following format

```
diskutil eraseDisk {filesystem} {Name to use} /dev/{disk identifier}
```

and I get an error in response. `Error: -69877: Couldn't open device`.

Question 2: How can I delete this damn thing?

EDIT: The full results I have now (updated as I am running Boot Camp Assistant with a USB inserted).

```
/dev/disk0
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         499.2 GB   disk0s2
3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           *498.9 GB   disk1
                              Logical Volume on disk0s2
                              301AF6C2-E123-4901-9BD5-3DD9B1AFD25C
                              Unlocked Encrypted
/dev/disk2
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *2.0 GB     disk2
1:                 DOS_FAT_32 WININSTALL              2.0 GB     disk2s1
/dev/disk3
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:     Apple_partition_scheme                        *1.2 GB     disk3
1:        Apple_partition_map                         4.1 KB     disk3s1
2:                  Apple_HFS                         2.3 MB     disk3s2
/dev/disk4
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:                            Boot Camp              *1.4 GB     disk4
```

Comment: Could you publish the full result of the diskutil

Comment: Sure, but the first two are what you would expect.

Comment: What is it? diskutil info disk3s1

Comment: can it be ejected /unmounted ?

Comment: I can unmount the disk. `Unmount of all volumes on disk3 was successful`. What is it? I have no idea.

Comment: What model Mac is this?

Comment: @user3439894 OS X Yosemite, Version 10.10.3

Comment: @ShanZhengYang, I didn't ask what version of OS X you're using I asked what model of Mac is it.

Comment: @user3439894 Um, oh. What a strange question. MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012)

Comment: Why is that a strange question?  What's strange is seeing a 1.4 GB Boot Camp partition considering no supported version of Windows on a 2012 Mac can be installed in that small of a partition.  Anyway instead of looking at the output of diskutil try looking at Storage in System Information as it may give you better info to help determine what the disk is.  Although now that it's ejected it will not show under Storage so you'll have to wait until next time if there is one.  Also based on the limited info about /dev/disk3 could it have been a .dmg file?

Comment: I'm guessing that Boot Camp disk is the one for Windows drivers, rather than Windows itself.

Comment: @Froggard That's correct. 
What's the best way to deal with these? Erase disk? That doesn't work for me.

Comment: @user3439894 Understand your question now. 
I am trying to partition my HD using the newest version of Yosemite. Yosemite doesn't allow you to manually chose the size of your partition. So, I'm forced to try Bootcamp to partition my HD. This causes more of a headache.